# ODBC Data in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rodbc

Is there a way to get data from an ODBC database outside of a reactive function?  I've seen in many examples, but I can't seem to get the data when the query is outside of the reactive?

**Server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)
library(dplyr)


LIMS <- odbcConnect(dsn = "LIMS", uid="unit", pwd="unit",readOnlyOptimize = TRUE)
first <-sqlQuery(LIMS,paste("SELECT ID_NUMERIC, ANALYSIS, SAMPLE_NAME, SAMPLED_DATE, COMPONENT_NAME, DATE_COMPLETED, RESULT_TEXT FROM SAMP_TEST_RESULT WHERE (ANALYSIS LIKE '%85W%')"),dec=getOption("dec"))
odbcClose(LIMS)

shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$chart <- renderDataTable({first()})
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('data_', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(final(), file)
    })
```

**UI.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)


shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Data Visualization Tool",  
             tags$head(
               tags$img(src="logo.jpg", height="150px",width="150px",align="right")
             )),


             column(width=10,
                    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
                      tabPanel("Chart",htmlOutput("chart1"),align="left"),
                      tabPanel("Table",dataTableOutput("chart"),align="left",downloadLink('downloadData', 'Download')),

                      ))
             )))
  )  
))
```

Error:

```
> shiny::runApp()

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6116
Warning: closing unused RODBC handle 5
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? Since we don't have the ODBC set up as you it's not easy to reproduce. Have you tried just `output$chart <- renderDataTable(first)`?

Comment: @MrFlick  Post has been updated to show error

Comment: Are you still getting these errors after using MrFlick's suggestion? I see nothing about you `first` object to suggest that it is reactive, so I wouldn't refer to it as a reactive object.

Comment: MrFlick's recommendation did the trick.  It was a remnant of an old code when I used GoogleVis for charting.